# How to update Value before render()

Tags: react-native

I have my app but I got a problem with **render()**. I want to do **AsyncStorage.getItem** before render() method. Here is the  code:

**The constructor:**

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {displayName: '', avatar:'',isLoading: false};
        console.log('Construtor()');
    }
```

**I want to do something here before render**

```
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('localData', (err, result) => {
        let tmp_localData = JSON.parse(result);
        this.state.displayName = tmp_localData['User']['displayName'];
        this.state.avatar = tmp_localData['User']['avatar'];
        console.log('component didmount');
    });
}
```

**My render method**

```
  render(){
    const {principal, imagem, titulo, conteudo, rodape, 
    texto,imgConteudo,imgTop,box} = myStyle;

    return(
            <View style={titulo}>
                <Text>    </Text>
                <Text>Nome da Loja</Text>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> {this.props.navigator.push({id: 'Users'});}} style={box}
                                    activeOpacity={1} underlayColor={'white'}>
                    <Image source={caminhoUsers} style={[imgTop]}/>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
```

I try everything but nothing works. Would someone explain me what I have to do to execute something before render?

Comment: use componentWillMount or paste the Async code in your constructor! componentDidMount is called after render

Comment: Or you can use async await and all a preloader till the data is loaded

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
async componentWillMount() {
    var Result = await AsyncStorage.getItem('localData');
    console.log("componentWillMount"+ JSON.stringify(Result));
    // perform actions
}

render (){
   console.log("render);
   return(
     // your code
   );
}
```

According to the lifecycle, componentWillMount() will execute before render(). Refer to this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting)

Comment: I think we can't use async directly on the life cycle methods!

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // make sure you cahnge the value of isLoading
    this.state = {displayName: '', avatar:'', isLoading: true };
    console.log('Construtor()');

    //Call the function
    this.loadData();
}

async loadData() {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('localData', (err, result) => {
             let tmp_localData = JSON.parse(result);
             this.state.displayName = tmp_localData['User']['displayName'];
             this.state.avatar = tmp_localData['User']['avatar'];
             this.setState({ isLoading: false });
             console.log('component didmount');
         });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

render() {
   // Here goes the render
   if ( this.state.isLoading ) {
       return (
      // The data to be shown after data load
         <View style={styles.overlay}>
           <Text>Loading</Text>
         </View>
      };
   }

   return (
      // The data to be shown after data load
   };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   overlay: {
      position: 'absolute',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      zIndex: 100,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
   }
});
```

If you find any issue please let me know! If you really need a preloader along with this example I am happy to help you.

I added comments in may places read them and change the code accordingly!

Comment: I try what you said but does not work and I try componentWillMount too but the **render()** execute before componentWillMount. more help please

Comment: @BráulioJoelson I added comments in many places read them and change the code accordingly!

Comment: I initially kept the state as `loading: true` then once the data is loaded set the state to false and render the data on the page?? Did that work? If that worked consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick button at the left side of this answer.

Comment: I have saw your coments. some magic happend i don't know how but i will explain. I do what you said to do. I change for true value my state variable  **isLoading: true** and i put just this line : **this.setState({ isLoading: false });**
I did not write the condition **if(this.state.isLoading)**  in the render.
I use debug mod in the browser and i see that , in my opinion, the render execute twice and your code Works :)

Comment: First render for the preloader and second for the data that will be displayed! Don't worry about performance.And I am glad that It worked for you ;)